# Upload a file to Zippyshare.com using mechanize under Python

Tags: python, file-upload, upload, mechanize

I'm trying to upload file to `Zippyshare.com` using Python with `mechanize`.

There is a HTML uploader in this page: http://www.zippyshare.com/sites/index_old.jsp

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.set_handle_refresh(False)
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
browser.open('http://www.zippyshare.com/sites/index_old.jsp')
browser.select_form(nr=1)
browser.form.add_file(open('/home/aaa.txt', 'rb'), 'text/plain', 'aaa.txt')
browser.submit()
```

The following script could select form and perform the submit action successfully.

However, nothing is uploaded.

Is there any wrong with the `form.add_file` section? And how to write the correct `add_file` method for `Zippyshare.com`? Thanks very much.

Comment: May be, you can use `requests` library to upload file?